# two clojure map refs as elements of each other

Tags: clojure, circular-reference, refs

I have two maps in refs and want to assoc them to each other in one transaction.

My function looks like this:

```
(defn assoc-two
  [one two]
  (let [newone (assoc @one :two two)
        newtwo (assoc @two :one one)]
    (ref-set one newone)
    (ref-set two newtwo)))
```

Now i am calling `assoc-two` like this:

```
(dosync (assoc-two (ref {}) (ref {})))
```

Im getting and StackOverflowError at this point.

I also tried this:

```
(defn alter-two
  [one two]
  (alter one assoc :two two)
  (alter two assoc :one one))
```

Is there away to do this in way that `one` has an entry referencing `two` and vice versa and still being in one transaction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stack overflow does not occur until you try to print one of the circular references, e.g. at the REPL.

```
so.core=> (def a (ref {}))
#'so.core/a
so.core=> (def b (ref {}))
#'so.core/b
so.core=> (do (dosync (alter-two a b)) :success)
:success
so.core=> (= b (:two @a))
true
so.core=> (= a (:one @b))
true
```

Obviously printing a circularly referenced object like this will be problematic, but see [this recent question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25418005/1756702) on disabling default printing of contents of reference types

```
(remove-method print-method clojure.lang.IDeref)

(dosync (alter-two (ref {}) (ref {})))
;=> {:one #<Ref clojure.lang.Ref@7f1f91ac>} 
;   (prints the second ref without attempting to print its circular contents)
```

Comment: Oh, i might have guessed that. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The answer can be found a few posts down, this is simply the REPL trying to print your recursive structure.
You have to either remove the print method:

```
(remove-method print-method clojure.lang.IDeref)
```

Or add a print method that handles your specific case, this method has to be more specific than the common `clojure.lang.IDeref`