# suppress output in REPL

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

When calling a function that returns something the REPL prints the output. How to suppress this printing without resorting to temporarily adding `nil` as the last line in a function?

Comment: Why would you need such functionality? Is the output too large or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fairly easy to do. If, for instance, you have a function named `f`, then as you know, you can call it like this:

```
(f)
;; hello yes this is f
;;=> :huge
```

But if you want to ignore the output, you can do this instead:

```
(do (f) nil)
;; hello yes this is f
;;=> nil
```

You could also define an `ignore` function to do this for you if you feel like it:

```
(def ignore (constantly nil))

(ignore (f))
;; hello yes this is f
;;=> nil
```

Comment: I find myself playing with `->>` during development a lot, so defining such an ignore function will be useful. Also, this topic is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417958/suppress-the-printing-of-the-data-an-atom-holds-in-the-repl-or-ref-agent